# Why does co_nlocals return 3, while co_names returns an empty tuple?

Tags: python

According to [Python's doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), the `co_names` attribute on a `code` object returns a tuple containing the names of all local variables of the given function, while `co_nlocals` returns the number of all local variables.

Taking the following function as an example:

```
def foo(x, y, z):
    pass
```

`foo.__code__.co_names` returns an empty tuple, and that makes sense since the function has **no** local variables — only arguments.

However, `foo.__code__.co_nlocals` returns the value `3`, even though there are no local variables in the function as testified by the `co_names` attribute.

```
foo.__code__.co_names # ()
foo.__code__.co_nlocals # 3
```

Why is this so?

Comment: A function parameter is exactly the same thing as a local variable, except that it already has a value when the function starts executing.

Comment: Probably the names are in `co_varnames`

Comment: @user13044086 The names do show up in ```co_varnames```, but according to the doc, ```co_nlocals``` returns the number of local variables, and so if ```co_names``` doesn't show anything, then ```co_nlocals``` should return ```0```.

Comment: [CPython PR still open since 2017](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2743)  

Comment: I just read that it was a documentation error. These errors do a lot than can be stated.